# Question on two intersecting circles at two points

Tags: geometry, circles

Two intersecting circles $S$ and $T$ in the plane intersect at two distinct points $A$ and $B$ and the center of $T$ lies on $S$. Points $C$ and $D$ are on $S$ and $T$ respectively with $C,B,D$ are collinear. Let point $E$ on $T$ such that $DE$ is parallel to $AC$. How do I show that $AE=AB$?[image]

Comment: You have asked good questions on this site, so you should know how to ask a good question. So add more information: What work have you done on this problem so far? Just where are you stuck?

Comment: I strongly recommend to add a picture! :)

Comment: **Hint:** Point *E* is fixed, and does not depend on the position of *C* on *S*.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in question, center of $T$ lies on $S$. Name it $O$. So we will have a cyclic quadrilateral $AOBC$. Then $$\overline{AO}=\overline{BO}=R_{\bigcirc T} \Longrightarrow \angle OAB = \angle OBA \tag{1}$$
By properties of cyclic quadrilaterals
$$\angle OCB = \angle OAB \tag{2}$$
$$\angle OCA = \angle OBA \tag{3}$$
From $(1)$,$(2)$ and $(3)$ $$\angle OAB = \frac{\angle C}{2} \tag{♥}$$
There is another cyclic quadrilateral,$AEDB$.By properties of cyclic quadrilaterals
$$\angle BAE+\angle D=180^\circ \tag{4}$$
Quadrilateral $ACDE$ is a trapezoid and $AC$ and $DE$ are it bases. So $$\angle C + \angle D = 180^\circ \tag{5}$$
From $(4)$ and $(5)$ $$\angle BAE = \angle C \tag{♦}$$Finally,From $(♥)$ and $(♦)$ $$\angle OAB =\angle OAE $$
Now it is easy to show $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle AOE$ are congruent.So $AB=AE$.

Comment: what is meant by $R_{\bigcirc T}$

Comment: @Ayushakj radius of circle $T$

Comment: how to get Quadrilateral ACDE is a trapezoid

Comment: @AyushJaiswal it is mentioned in question that $AC$ is parallel to $DE$